# логика при работе с псевдоклассом :hover

Tags: css

```
li.top ul.submenu{display:none;}          
li.top:hover ul.submenu {display:block;}
```

Первое правило прячет список-подменю.
Второе - показывает подменю, если на верхний пункт меню (родитель), в котором находится подменю, наведут курсор.
Общий принцип - родительский элемент реагирует на наведение мыши и изменяет свойства элементов-потомков.

Мы задаем для элемента `li.top ul.submenu` (контекстный селектор), тогда почему правило применяется к родителю (в примере `2`), а тот изменяет свойство элементов-потомков, чтобы подменю появилось, если даже само свойство не наследуется.

То, что на подменю не навести курсор это понятно - оно скрыто.
Интересен принцип работы (есть ли какое то правило).
Почему свойство применяется к родителю во втором примере?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> li.top:hover ul.submenu {display:block;}
> ```

Надо что-то такое, чтобы только один потомок реагировал:

```
li.top:hover > ul.submenu {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

потому что свойство наследуется потомками => ты навел на родителя отреагировали дети, у детей может быть свои потомки, и это упрощает работу с элементами навигации.

Comment: @BlackStar1991- да, но тут я даю конкретики и говорю, чтобы свойство применилось именно к потомку(дочернему элементу) ul.submenu,который вложен в предка(родителя) li.top... по правилам я применяю свойство именно к ul.submenu. Или я что-то упускаю. Не могу понять именно этот момент

Comment: Не наследуется свойство, тут селектор такой.

Comment: @Qwertiy-  вот именно, что даже свойство не наследуемое... тогда почему родитель изменяет свойства потомков, это особенность :hover?  или что то другое... по каким правилам это работает

Comment: @Александр, я ж уже ответил. Наследование не при чём.